# How to get PDF output in one CSV line

Tags: c#, excel, itext

with my program the csv makes a new line with every input. Like:

- John;Fellon
- Marblestreet;45

Is there a way to get it all in one line ?

My current code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\burak\Desktop\todo";
    StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\burak\Desktop\todo\test.csv");
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file);
        string currentText ="";

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
            currentText = string.Join(";", currentText.Split(' ', ':', '/'));
            currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
            // text.Append(currentText);
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
        
        text.ToString();
        write.Write(currentText);
        Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());
    }
    write.Close();
}
```

**What I tried:**

to get the spaces to combine it to one line, but that didn't work at all..

Comment: This will crash as soon as you have more than 1 page, won't it? You are closing the reader _inside_ the loop.

Comment: No he does not. The write.Close is at the end of the Main Function. He weirdly has some brackets that shouldn't be there. But the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be there is a CR or LF in the input text. You can try this:

`write.Write(currentText.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", ""));`

Answer (score 0):

To remove all LineBreaks we can replace them with an empty string. To get the new lines of the current System use `System.Environment.NewLine`. Now all the PDF text from all pages is on the same line. To now add a line break for each new PDF File we can add a `System.Environment.NewLine` at the end of the string and then write the whole PDF to the CSV file.

**Example:**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    // ...
    StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\burak\Desktop\todo\test.csv");
    // ...

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)) {
        // ...

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++) {
            // ...
            currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
            // ...
        }

        // Replace newLines
        currentText = currentText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
        // Add newLine to currentText
        currentText += System.Environment.NewLine;
        write.Write(currentText);
    }
    write.Close();
}
```

Comment: won't that cause the CSV to be overwritten by the next pdf ?

Comment: @JimmyFellon Now each new PDF should start on a newline.